# How to get meta data of the pipeline in DataFlow of Azure data factory? Want to create a debug pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a task where I need to create a dashboard that will provide details of the pipeline which was run in azure datafactory. For this I want to load the data into SQL. The intention is to test the performance of any dataflow. The pipeline will be a plug and play model where we will just drag and drop the dataflow to be tested, make the connections and at every pipeline run, get the following data from the pipeline. Below are the column names that I want to fill:

```
**Sr No:**               Auto Increment, Primary key
**pipeline ID:**         <ID of pipeline run>
**Dataflow Start Time:** ddmmyy HH:SS
**Dataflow end time:**   ddmmyy HH:SS
**Duration to acquire compute:** In seconds
**Data input:**           Size of data read from source
**Data output:**          Size of data written to sink
**Run type:**             Triggered / Manual(Debug) run
**DataFlow Status:** Failed / Success
```

I can see metadata blade to get metadata of source. However I cannot seem to find resources to get other information. Please help if you know how to create such a pipeline in Azure Data Factory.

Comment: are you looking for apart from these [Monitor Data Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-monitoring) & [Mapping data flows performance and tuning guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance) ?  You can use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory) in pipeline to get the information or use Diagnostic setting to query from ADF resource logs

Comment: I want the stats provided in [Monitor Data Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-monitoring)  but need these values (like rows written, success or fail etc) in SQL. Any way to extract these stats after a particular dataflow runs? Aim is to share these stats to someone who is not a part of Azure, so that they can do analysis. So these people cannot login to monitor the pipeline run, They need all the data exported to SQL table.

Comment: The output JSON from the data flow activity will have those stats. You can have ADF store them in logs by turning on Azure Monitor integration. Or you can parse the output of the activity in the pipeline.

Comment: Was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Oh yes it. It took me sometime to replicate this but got almost what I wanted. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebActivity` to call API and get the details, later copy that to a SQL sink.

Here is one example:

1. [Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory)

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01`

Replace the actual values in the placeholders.

[image]

```
Output
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/B83C1EE3-C5B6-44FB-B5BA-2A83A074C23F/RESOURCEGROUPS/myrg/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/KTESTADF/pipelineruns/c619e850-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4b73dcacb9d8",
            "runId": "c619e850-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4b73dcacb9d8",
            "debugRunId": null,
            "runGroupId": "c619e850-xxxx-xxxx-8d0c-4b73dcacb9d8",
            "pipelineName": "partiion_parquets",
            "parameters": {},
            "invokedBy": {
                "id": "216e5917354a41b983f82d8ceda53789",
                "name": "Manual",
                "invokedByType": "Manual"
            },
            "runStart": "2021-10-12T13:00:12.9095561Z",
            "runEnd": "2021-10-12T13:03:17.9824334Z",
            "durationInMs": 185072,
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "message": "",
            "output": null,
            "lastUpdated": "2021-10-12T13:03:17.9824334Z",
            "annotations": [],
            "runDimension": {},
            "isLatest": true
        }
    ],
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads": "11999",
        "x-ms-request-id": "4373f002-b352-4824-857b-15f5325241ae",
        "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "4373f002-b352-4824-857b-15f5325241ae",
        "x-ms-routing-request-id": "CENTRALUS:20211012T131047Z:4373f002-b352-4824-857b-15f5325241ae",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Tue, 12 Oct 2021 13:10:46 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "717",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Central US)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Next for example, using the pipeline run ID from the earlier output, call api to get Data flow details.

2. [Activity Runs - Query By Pipeline Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run)

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01`

[image]

```
Output
{
    "value": [
        {
            "activityRunEnd": "2021-10-12T13:03:17.1874105Z",
            "activityName": "Data flow1",
            "activityRunStart": "2021-10-12T13:00:14.7523815Z",
            "activityType": "ExecuteDataFlow",
            "durationInMs": 182435,
            "retryAttempt": null,
            "error": {
                "errorCode": "",
                "message": "",
                "failureType": "",
                "target": "Data flow1",
                "details": ""
            },
            "activityRunId": "5e7aece7-5fb7-4ffd-939e-d01d3fcb494a",
            "iterationHash": "",
            "input": {
                "dataflow": {
                    "referenceName": "generateParquet",
                    "type": "DataFlowReference",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "datasetParameters": {
                        "source1": {},
                        "sink1": {}
                    }
                },
                "staging": {},
                "compute": {
                    "coreCount": 8,
                    "computeType": "General"
                },
                "traceLevel": "Fine",
                "dataFlowETag": "48019f9b-0000-0300-0000-616475e20000"
            },
            "linkedServiceName": "",
            "output": {
                "runStatus": {
                    "computeAcquisitionDuration": 107335,
                    "version": "20211011.2",
                    "profile": {
                        "source1": {
                            "computed": [],
                            "lineage": {},
                            "dropped": 0,
                            "drifted": 0,
                            "newer": 16,
                            "total": 16,
                            "updated": 0
                        },
                        "sink1": {
                            "computed": [],
                            "lineage": {
                                "CompanyName": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "CompanyName"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "LastName": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "LastName"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "MiddleName": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "MiddleName"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "PasswordSalt": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "PasswordSalt"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "ModifiedDate": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "ModifiedDate"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "path": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "path"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "rowguid": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "rowguid"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "Title": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "Title"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "NameStyle": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "NameStyle"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "CustomerID": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "CustomerID"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "FirstName": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "FirstName"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "Suffix": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "Suffix"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "Phone": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "Phone"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "PasswordHash": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "PasswordHash"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "SalesPerson": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "SalesPerson"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "EmailAddress": {
                                    "mapped": true,
                                    "from": [
                                        {
                                            "source": "source1",
                                            "columns": [
                                                "EmailAddress"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "dropped": 0,
                            "drifted": 0,
                            "newer": 0,
                            "total": 16,
                            "updated": 16
                        }
                    },
                    "metrics": {
                        "sink1": {
                            "format": "parquet",
                            "stages": [
                                {
                                    "stage": 1,
                                    "partitionTimes": [
                                        525
                                    ],
                                    "lastUpdateTime": "2021-10-12 13:02:50.453",
                                    "bytesWritten": 0,
                                    "bytesRead": 199491,
                                    "partitionStatus": "Success",
                                    "streams": {
                                        "source1": {
                                            "count": 847,
                                            "cached": false,
                                            "totalPartitions": 1,
                                            "partitionStatus": "Success",
                                            "partitionCounts": [
                                                847
                                            ],
                                            "type": "source"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "target": "sink1",
                                    "time": 640,
                                    "progressState": "Completed"
                                },
                                {
                                    "stage": 2,
                                    "partitionTimes": [
                                        3436,
                                        3373,
                                        3441,
                                        3475,
                                        2304,
                                        2321,
                                        2364,
                                        2291,
                                        1989,
                                        2435
                                    ],
                                    "lastUpdateTime": "2021-10-12 13:02:58.897",
                                    "bytesWritten": 177728,
                                    "bytesRead": 0,
                                    "partitionStatus": "Success",
                                    "streams": {
                                        "sink1": {
                                            "count": 847,
                                            "cached": false,
                                            "totalPartitions": 10,
                                            "partitionStatus": "Success",
                                            "partitionCounts": [
                                                84,
                                                85,
                                                85,
                                                85,
                                                85,
                                                85,
                                                85,
                                                85,
                                                84,
                                                84
                                            ],
                                            "type": "sink"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "target": "sink1",
                                    "time": 8452,
                                    "progressState": "Completed"
                                }
                            ],
                            "sinkPostProcessingTime": 0,
                            "data": [],
                            "store": "blob",
                            "rowsWritten": 847,
                            "details": {
                                "postCommandsDuration": [
                                    3
                                ],
                                "preCommandsDuration": [
                                    1
                                ]
                            },
                            "sources": {
                                "source1": {
                                    "rowsRead": 847,
                                    "store": "blob",
                                    "details": {
                                        "fileSystemInitDuration": [
                                            7751
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "format": "delimited"
                                }
                            },
                            "sinkProcessingTime": 12380
                        }
                    },
                    "dsl": "\nsource() ~> source1\n\nsource1 sink() ~> sink1"
                },
                "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Central US)",
                "billingReference": {
                    "activityType": "executedataflow",
                    "billableDuration": [
                        {
                            "meterType": "General",
                            "duration": 0.3691165737777778,
                            "unit": "coreHour",
                            "sessionType": "JobCluster"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "reportLineageToPurview": {
                    "status": "NotReported"
                }
            },
            "userProperties": {},
            "pipelineName": "partiion_parquets",
            "pipelineRunId": "c619e850-c7de-4d1f-8d0c-4b73dcacb9d8",
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "recoveryStatus": "None",
            "integrationRuntimeNames": [
                "defaultintegrationruntime"
            ],
            "executionDetails": {
                "integrationRuntime": [
                    {
                        "name": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
                        "type": "Managed",
                        "computeType": "General",
                        "coreCount": "8"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/B83C1EE3-xxxx-xxxx-B5BA-2E83A074C23K/RESOURCEGROUPS/myrg/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/KTESTADF/pipelineruns/c619e850-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4b73dcacb9d8/activityruns/5e7aece7-xxxx-4ffd-939e-d01d3fcb494a"
        }
    ],
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads": "11999",
        "x-ms-request-id": "e8fa08f2-594a-4464-b43e-d71104c1950c",
        "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "e8fa08f2-594a-4464-b43e-d71104c1950c",
        "x-ms-routing-request-id": "CENTRALUS:20211012T131050Z:e8fa08f2-594a-4464-b43e-d71104c1950c",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Tue, 12 Oct 2021 13:10:49 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "4307",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Central US)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From the above you can filter for `"activityType": "ExecuteDataFlow"` , `durationInMs`, `activityRunStart`, `activityRunEnd`, `invokedByType`, `input`, `output` and other metrics.

Just follow [Azure Data Factory version 2 (V2) REST API operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/v2), parameterize selected outputs and store in variables if necessary. Using `Add dynamic content` build URL and JSON request body appropriately.