# API for Getting ADF pipeline details

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rest-api

I was looking for an API which gives me the details of a Azure Datafactory Pipeline
including start time,end time, duration etc. This is required to generate a report without manually looking into the ADF monitoring window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of pipeline runs using  [Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory)  and then for each result run [Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory]

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Checkout the sample request [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory#pipelineruns_querybyfactory)

You can pick the necessary fields from the response body.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "runId": "2f7fdb90-5df1-4b8e-ac2f-064cfa58202b",
      "pipelineName": "examplePipeline",
      "parameters": {
        "OutputBlobNameList": "[\"exampleoutput.csv\"]"
      },
      "invokedBy": {
        "id": "80a01654a9d34ad18b3fcac5d5d76b67",
        "name": "Manual"
      },
      "runStart": "2018-06-16T00:37:44.6257014Z",
      "runEnd": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
      "durationInMs": 28105,
      "status": "Succeeded",
      "message": "",
      "lastUpdated": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
      "annotations": [],
      "runDimension": {
        "JobId": "79c1cc52-265f-41a5-9553-be65e736fbd3"
      }
    },
    {
      "runId": "16ac5348-ff82-4f95-a80d-638c1d47b721",
      "pipelineName": "examplePipeline",
      "parameters": {
        "OutputBlobNameList": "[\"exampleoutput.csv\"]"
      },
      "invokedBy": {
        "id": "7c5fd7ef7e8a464b98b931cf15fcac66",
        "name": "Manual"
      },
      "runStart": "2018-06-16T00:39:49.2745128Z",
      "runEnd": null,
      "durationInMs": null,
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "message": "",
      "lastUpdated": "2018-06-16T00:39:51.216097Z",
      "annotations": [],
      "runDimension": {
        "JobId": "84a3c493-0628-4b44-852f-ef5b3a11bdab"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

And here is a simple WebActivity setup:

[image]

[image]

Further, you can find similar queries answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69616232/15969417) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69542833/15969417)