# Azure Data Factory find which pipeline in a sequence failed

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline (PL_Main) containing a set of Execute pipeline activities in sequence, as the below image depicts:
[image]
Now, I was trying to create an activity (executed after PL_Main completion) that allowed me to understand if any of the 'childs' Execute Pipeline activities (PL_1, PL_2, PL3.1, PL_3.2) failed.

However, according my understanding thee pipelines output contains only the RunId and PipelineName. Is there a way that I can find what were the pipelines in my execution chain that failed (or at least the 1st one failling) and store their RunId in as a parameter for my next activity (New Activity) ?

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: Hey, is your ask to pass the pipeline runid of which ever childpipeline failed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to pass the pipelinerunid of the failed activity within Main pipeline, you need to deign the pipeline in below way :

[image]

JSON:

```
{
"name": "pipeline8",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "pipeline": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline7",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "waitOnCompletion": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Execute Pipeline2",
            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "pipeline": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline9",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "waitOnCompletion": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Execute Pipeline3",
            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline2",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "pipeline": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline10",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "waitOnCompletion": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Execute Pipeline4",
            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline2",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "pipeline": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline11",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "waitOnCompletion": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Fail1",
            "type": "Fail",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "message": {
                    "value": "@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineRunId",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "errorCode": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Fail2",
            "type": "Fail",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline2",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "message": {
                    "value": "@activity('Execute Pipeline2').output.pipelineRunId",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "errorCode": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Fail3",
            "type": "Fail",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline3",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "activity": "Fail5",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Skipped"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "message": "@activity('Execute Pipeline3').output.pipelineRunId",
                "errorCode": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Fail4",
            "type": "Fail",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline4",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "activity": "Fail5",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Skipped"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "message": "@activity('Execute Pipeline4').output.pipelineRunId",
                "errorCode": "4"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Fail5",
            "type": "Fail",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline3",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline4",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "message": {
                    "value": "@concat(activity('Execute Pipeline3').output.pipelineRunId,';',activity('Execute Pipeline4').output.pipelineRunId)",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "errorCode": "5"
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "test": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "spt": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "final": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

My blog for reference:  https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

Note: the fail activities capture the pipelinerunid

Finaly to capture the ID:
[image]

```
@activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach also, to get the failed pipeline run id.

For this **name the Execute pipeline activities name same as child pipeline names**.

First get the Failed Execute pipeline activity name (Pipeline name) in the main pipeline using the error message.

Error message:

[image]

Use set variable to get this.

[image]

Get the pipeline name from the error message.

use the below expression for that.

```
@substring(variables('error'), add(indexOf(variables('error'),'target'),7), sub(indexOf(variables('error'),' failed'),add(indexOf(variables('error'),'target'),7)))
```

[image]

You can see that we got the pipeline name in the variable

[image]

Now get all the pipeline runs from the [Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP) command.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Use this in web activity.

This will give you **all pipeline runs details with names and run ids** Json which you can see in the above documentation.

Now compare our **pipeline name from variable** in this JSON and get that particular run id which is our required failed pipeline run id. Use ForEach activity or filter for that.

**Reference:**

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70449862/api-for-getting-adf-pipeline-details) for reference by [KarthikBhyresh-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969417/karthikbhyresh-mt)