Create a ADF pipeline to get status of other pipelines
I want to automate a process we have in our team, that consists to perform a daily check of 23 pipelines. Essentially, we need to all of these pipelines getting a status, fill a excel sheet and then load it using python and run a script that creates a bunch of statistics.
This doesn't make sense at all to me, so I want to automate this.
First step is to stop going to ADF and manually check status of my pipelines.
But I have no idea how to do that. What do I need to do? I was expecting ADF was storing this in a database, but seems it's not the case. So how can I get it?
One solution seems to get the status directly from the pipeline itself and store it:
How to fetch the status of Execute pipeline activity and pass it to stored procedure activity in ADF
But I want to check status when I want/need, so I believe the information we get on "Monitor" tab must be stored somewhere and can be accessed somehow.
Any help?
Thanks!

Meanwhile I've discovered this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP#pipelineruns_querybyfactory
And this question here on stack overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536593/how-to-get-meta-data-of-the-pipeline-in-dataflow-of-azure-data-factory-want-to/69542833#69542833
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614957/get-azure-data-factory-logs/69616232#69616232
I believe I've just answered to my own question!
